# Spark Structured Streaming: howto achive same order on processing Kafka topic and its backup on S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

### Question

*How to achieve idempotance (the same event order) between processing Kafka topic and it S3 backup with Spark Structured Streaming?*

See `# QUESTION:` comment at Code Example below.

### Use case

Suppose you have exactly the same use case as Uber - stream processing that is used for both: low-latency and historical analysis. For real-life example see "Motivation" section of [Designing a Production-Ready Kappa Architecture for Timely Data Stream Processing](https://eng.uber.com/kappa-architecture-data-stream-processing/):

You storing data in Kafka, archiving them to S3 with [Kafka Connect AWS S3 Sink](https://dzone.com/articles/why-you-should-and-how-to-archive-your-kafka-data). And stream processing is done by Spark Structured Streaming. You decided to solve the issue with ["Combined approach"](https://eng.uber.com/kappa-architecture-data-stream-processing/) section: run the code in background backfilling mode over S3 (Kafka backuped topics).

### Code example

```
def some_processing(spark: SparkSession, stream: DataFrame, backfilling_mode: bool):
  input_stream = read(spark, 'input_topic', backfilling_mode)
  processed_stream = input_stream \
    .withWatermark('event_time', '10 seconds') \
    .groupBy(window('event_time', '10 seconds', '10 seconds'), 'user_id') \
    .agg(sum(col('price'))) \
    .join(...)
  write(processed_stream, 'output_topic', backfilling_mode)

def read(spark: SparkSession, topic_name: str, backfilling_mode: bool) -> DataFrame:
  """Reads data from Kafka topic or its S3 backup"""
  # QUESTION: how Spark achieve the same order on backfilling_mode=True and backfilling_mode=False
  if backfilling_mode:
    stream = spark \
      .readStream \
      .schema(input_schema) \ 
      .format('com.databricks.spark.avro') \
      .option('maxFilesPerTrigger', 20) \
      .load('/s3_base_bath/{}'.format(topic_name)) 
  else:
    stream = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format('kafka') \
      .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'host1:port1,host2:port2') \
      .option('subscribe', topic_name) \
      .load() 


def write(stream: DataFrame, topic_name: str, backfilling_mode: bool):
  """Writes data to Kafka topic or its S3 backup"""
  if backfilling_mode:
    stream \
      .writeStream \
      .trigger(processingTime='60 seconds') \
      .format('com.databricks.spark.avro') \
      .option('path', '/s3_base_bath/{}'.format(topic_name)) \
      .start() \
      .awaitTermination()
  else:
    stream \
      .writeStream \
      .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds') \
      .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'host1:port1,host2:port2') \
      .option('topic', 'output_topic')
      .format('kafka') \
      .start() \
      .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: The data within each Avro file depends on your partitioning settings of Kafka Connect... Use the timestamp partitioner of 10 or more seconds, then you should expect to be able to sum each file

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the answer! Suppose I've already partitioned Kafka topic on S3 by 1 minute ingestion time window. For example, `s3://base_path/input_topic/year=2021/month=03/day=10/w=1` or `s3://base_path/input_topic/year=2021/month=03/day=10/w=1440`. Not sure if I need also partition by topic's partition key, but that may create small files issue. Anycase, the main part now is - *how to process only one window at a time with Spark Structured Streaming?* As far as I understand, `maxFilesPerTrigger ` config won't help you a lot

Comment: @OneCricketeer if I understood it correct from the article, the main reason to backfill in Spark's stream mode - is idempotance: Spark batch mode ignores watermarks and event-time windows. But without answering the question how to make Spark's stream mode process `w=1` partition before `w=2` it looks to have the same issue with idempotance, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with Spark. Was just commenting on how you've structured the files in the bucket

Comment: Looks like the only way to achieve that is to write a custom connector with Spark SourceV2 API (like Uber did)